# How to build a SOAP Web service Client in SEAM

Tags: java, web-services, soap, client, seam

I've been looking all over for this question... How do I build a soap web service client in SEAM?? it seems like a straightforward question-answer but I cant seem to make it work no matter how I try... If anyone has an example of what should be done I'd really apreciate it because I need to consume a web service from a legacy system, and all the help I come across on the internet is to make a WS, not how to consume one.

Thanx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog posting on [How to create and use a WebService with Axis 2 and Seam 2.x in JBoss 4.x](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-create-and-use-webservice-with.html)

This might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks!! I actually found your tutorial early on, and had built my client based on it all that I was missing was to place the jar of the client inside the JBoss\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\lib folder, because I kept getting a ClassNotFoundException and I had no idea it was from that, a friend helped me out on that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following links have good examples and documentation explaining what you need to do:

- [Accessing
  Seam WebServices from a standalone
  Client](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/AccessingSeamWebServicesFromAStandaloneClient)
- [Webservices
  chapter in the SEAM documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/webservices.html)